# ErrorDocument 404 parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am trying to set a custom error page in htaccess (locally on EasyPHP DevServer). I found that code but it only works if I define the project's directory (e.g. /myproject/index.php).

```
# Does not work
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# This works
ErrorDocument 404 /project/index.php
```

I tried to search for a method using REQUEST_URI (strip the filename and keeps the directory name only, match string before first slash basically) so that I won't need to define the project folder but I do not found anything. Did someone know how can I do that?

Comment: is it one question or two ? please specify what you need more?

Comment: Sorry, I need a htaccess code to auto detect the "parent folder", something like:

    # ${REQUEST_URI} e.g. /folder/file.php
    # I want to strip the file.php and leave the /folder/ and set it in the ErrorDocument
    ErrorDocument 404 ${REQUEST_URI}/index.php